# Coded UI: Find Element(s) by CSS Selector

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to build out a harness for a page so that we can write tests against it. What I would like to be able to do is use a CSS selector to find the given element or elements instead of manually modifying the SearchProperties or FilterProperties.For a web test the CSS Selector seems far more intuitive then the SearchProperties do. Is there some mechanism for doing this that I am simply not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

https://github.com/rpearsondev/CodedUI.jQueryExtensions/

It adds extension methods to the BrowserWindow object...

```
var example1 = browser.JQuerySelect<HtmlHyperlink>('a.class1');
var example2 = browser.JQuerySelect<HtmlListItem>('li.class2');
```

However, I will let you know I'm having issues with it complaining about casting errors regularly.

Answer (score 0):

As sjdirect noted, the jQuery extensions are probably the way to go if you want to use those type of selectors.

However, it seems that you may be interested in *some* abstraction that doesn't require directly setting search / filter properties on the UITestControl objects.

There are good abstractions that do not use the same selectors as jQuery, but provide a readable, consistent approach for finding elements in the page and interacting with them.

I would recommend also looking into [Code First](https://codeduicodefirst.codeplex.com/) and [CodedUI Fluent](https://github.com/spelltwister/CodedUIFluentExtensions) (I wrote the fluent extensions) or even [CodedUI Enhanced](https://github.com/icnocop/cuite) (CUITe).

These provide query support for that looks like (from CUITe):

```
// Launch the web browser and navigate to the homepage
BrowserWindowUnderTest browserWindow = BrowserWindowUnderTest.Launch("https://website.com");

// Enter the first name
browserWindow.Find<HtmlEdit>(By.Id("FirstName")).Text = "John";

// Enter the last name
browserWindow.Find<HtmlPassword>(By.Id("LastName")).Text ="Doe";

// Click the Save button
browserWindow.Find<HtmlInputButton>(By.Id("Save")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try browserWindow.executeJavascript if you return a control you found via css/xpath it returns the relevant uiControl object

```
const string javascript = "document.querySelector('{0}');";
var bw = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://rawstack.azurewebsites.net"));
string selector = "[ng-model='filterOptions.filterText']";
var control = bw.ExecuteScript(string.Format(javascript,selector));
HtmlEdit filter= control as HtmlEdit;
filter.Text = "Alien";
```